# image is blurry when assigned CSS properties

Tags: css, blurry

i have a question about a file i wanted to upload to my personal web.
I added a jpeg fromat of my CV to my website but when i apply CSS style

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; }
```

it makes the jpeg blurry (it has a lot of text and it is quite annoying) i have this style on many different pictures and it does nothing to them, it seems to blurry only this one, i tried diiferent export, png etc nothing helps.

When i remove the class atribute in html it looks sharp and normal.(but then it dosnt scale on mobile devices etc.) The image size doesnt change when there is the style present it remains the same size.

What could be a problem here? I am using Microsoft Edge to view the webpage.
[No blurr present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd9q5.jpg)
[Blurr when defined style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2bdC.jpg)

Comment: The styles inside `.img-fluid` has nothing to do with image quality. Your image is not large enough to look sharp on larger screens. You have to use a higher resolution image. PNG format is preferred.

Comment: Even if the png is 6000px it looks still the same, i can make it bigger as I want..., also like i said when i remove the class from html the image stays the same size on my screen.